# How to print multiple exceptions in an input file to an errors file?

Tags: java, exception

I'm in a computer science (java) class right now and our task is to create a program that reads integers from an input.txt file (the professor will have this) and prints out all the integers into an output.txt file.  Any exceptions/errors will need to be printed to an errors.txt file that our program creates.  (We are learning about Exceptions in class now).

My program is able to read from an input file and print out just the integers to an output.txt, but I'm having problems printing out all the exceptions that might occur.  For example, if the input file has "abc" as one of the lines, it should print out a message in the errors.txt file saying that it isn't an integer.

What happens with my program is that as soon as one exception is thrown, it doesn't keep going to print out all the other exceptions even if there are more to print.  It just stops at that point.

So for example, something like this:

```
try{        

            while (fileScan.hasNext())
            {
                num = fileScan.nextInt();
            }

    }catch(Exception e)
    {               
        erout.println(e); //prints the error to the file.
        fileScan.nextLine();
    }
```

erout is my PrintWriter object for the error.txt file.  fileScan for the input.txt.

I'm just not sure how to get it to go through all of the input.txt file and keep track of all the exceptions it will throw, then print all those to an error.txt file.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could move the `while` loop outside of the `try` statement.

```
while (fileScan.hasNext())
{
    try{        

            num = fileScan.nextInt();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {               
    erout.println(e); //prints the error to the file.
    fileScan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-order your `while` and `try`/`catch`:

```
List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
    try {
         num = fileScan.nextInt();
         // more code here to process num
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // Might also want to create a custom exception type to track
         // The line/file that the error occurred upon.
         exceptions.add(e);
         fileScan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dang, as I said in another comment, that was a really silly mistake.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

All you gotta do is move the try/catch within the while:

```
        while (fileScan.hasNext())
        {
            try {
                num = fileScan.nextInt();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                erout.println(e); //prints the error to the file.
                fileScan.nextLine();
            } 

        }
```

Comment: Dang, as I said in another comment, that was a really silly mistake.  Thanks. :)

Comment: no worries, happens when you're learning. Won't happen again I'm sure :)